# Is there a theorem to determine the elliptic curve parameters based on the group order?

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, elliptic-curve-generation

By Hasse's theorem we know that range of the group order of the elliptic curve. And similarly, there exist a theorem on the admissible order of elliptic curves. Suppose by the theorem on the admissible order of elliptic curve we know there exist a curve of desired order then how to determine the curve parameters. For example in case of simplified/short Weierstrass equation the value of the parameters $a,b$.

My question: is there a theorem to determine the curve parameters based on the group order? Does the form of the curve matter? The different forms of the curve are Weierstrass, Montgomery, and Edwards.

Comment: Note: I'm pretty sure that if you can count the points on an Edwards curve, then you can also count them on a Montgomery curve (and vice versa) as the two are usually birationally equivalent. BTW: [Schoof's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoof's_algorithm)

Comment: @SEJPM: actually, he isn't asking "given a curve, how many points on it"; instead, he's asking "given a target number of points (that's not impossible), how can I generate a curve with precisely that many points?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a method known as "Complex Multiplication". However, it is not simple at all, and tends to be overly expensive for most target orders. See [this article](http://users.uoa.gr/~kontogar/bibtex/SpringerLNCS.pdf) for some details. There is also the (theoretical) concern that a curve constructed that way may have a special structure though could possibly be leveraged into an attack one day; generally speaking, cryptographers do not like special cases and prefer the immunity of the herd by relying on random values in big sets (unless there is a performance advantage to be had with the special structure, in which case to Hell with it, let's milk the precious clock cycles -- that's how modern curves tend to be defined in fields of prime order $2^m-c$ with a very small $c$).

CM has been used to define [pairing-friendly curves](https://www.cryptojedi.org/papers/pfcpo.pdf) (curves that *have* a demonstrated special structure which is on the verge of being a weakness, but also enables nifty three-way protocols).

Comment: Related and maybe worth a read: [Harald Baier's dissertation on the subject of generating elliptic curves efficiently.](http://tuprints.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de/211/1/dissertation_harald_baier.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

There can be much simpler methods than CM for group orders of a specific form. For exemple if $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ and $b \not\equiv 0 \pmod p$, the curve $Y^2 = X^3 + b$ over $\mathbf{F}_p$ has $p+1$ points. (The proof of this is easy and left as an exercise.) Such methods are also used to easily construct "good enough" pairing-friendly curves.

As Thomas notes in the commants, the low embedding degree of those curves makes them simultaneously good for pairings and bad for elliptic-curve discrete-log based systems. Use with caution.

Comment: Take care that these curves have embedding degree 2, so they are much weaker than usual curves for "normal sizes" (e.g. 256 bits). This is a nice curve if you want to use a pairing and know what you are doing.